# Does a given time fall into a given time interval in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a time interval - 12:00 PM to 11:59 PM.
When the user enters the time as "06:15 PM", check against that interval.
If the time falls into that interval, return true else return false.
I searched for thisin Google, but I didn't get the correct solution.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
 String From = "12:00 PM";
 String to = "11:59 PM";

 String user_given_input = "06:15 PM";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it should work.

```
static boolean checkTimeInterval(String s) {
        String From = "12:00 PM";
        String to = "11:59 PM";
        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        boolean isLie = false;
        try {
            Date from = d.parse(From);
            Date too = d.parse(to);
            Date input = d.parse(s);

            if (input.before(too) && input.after(from)) {
                isLie = true;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Check input string format");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isLie;

    }
```

You may call this function as

```
checkTimeInterval("06:15 PM")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could parse it into a `Date` object using a `SimpleDateFormatter`.
After you've done that you can use `fromDate.before(user_given_input_date) && toDate.after(user_given_input_date)`.
assuming `fromDate`, `toDate` & `user_given_input_date` are `Date` objects

Comment: in this `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");` or `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");`

Comment: According to the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) it should be `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a") as you stated`